# How do I enable USB audio for GUI applications on Raspbian? (ALSA command line is working)

Tags: usb, audio, audio-playback, pixel

I'll say it again to be clear - *ALSA on the command line works fine* (after I delete/modify .asoundrc after it's auto-broken by PIXEL).

The most seemingly contemporary answer I've found on modern Raspbian ALSA config was [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40831/how-do-i-configure-my-sound-for-jasper-on-raspbian-jessie/40832#40832) (I have no idea where @Housni read about the `slots` option being needed for recent versions of Raspbian, though). It seems that ALSA on Raspberry Pi is a bit funny and I don't see any official docs that are relevant to non-standard audio anywhere (just directions on HDMI or the PWM outputs). I have looked at MANY websites, including raspi forums, this SE site, Adafruit, and the ALSA docs.

My situation:

- I can set my USB device to default for alsa, as either device 0 or 1, except...
- .asoundrc gets regenerated each login to LXDE/PIXEL. Somehow it knows where the built-in device is and selects that card. Doesn't matter if a good .asoundrc was there vs. no such file.
- So, by default, I get the built-in sound on the command line after login, but I can edit/delete `.asoundrc` and everything's fine on the CLI.
- The GUI (e.g., `pimixer` aka "Audio Device Manager") ONLY seems to see the built-in audio. The USB card is visible via e.g., `aplay -l`, but not in the pimixer drop-down.

Based on the [`pimixer` README](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pimixer), it seems PIXEL (aka sorta LXDE) is using Gstreamer for GUI stuff.

As far as I can tell, this issue could reside in:

- LXDE
- PIXEL LXDE mods
- Gstreamer
- the XFCE4 mixer settings (pimixer related stuff)
- Pulseaudio

I trashed my `.config` directory, and this doesn't change any behavior.

I'm open to simply using a different distro - I'm on an RPi3. I welcome solutions at any level!

I will also happily upvote comments / answers shedding light on some of the mysteries above, like:

- What is generating that `.asoundrc`?
- What sound framework is Chromium talking to?

UPDATES

- [this rpi SE post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54199/my-asoundrc-is-modified-every-reboot) describes the same issue. The fix doesn't work for me. It also doesn't explain what's going on - it feels like breaking the system, not understanding it.
- [this rpi forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=158618&p=1058696&hilit=.asoundrc#p1058696) explains how that doesn't work for some people and how you can just disable the internal audio. This also doesn't work - pimixer says "No ALSA audio devices were detected." (`aplay -l` still shows my USB device - a Blackjack Onyx.)

Comment: GUI apps use SDL for sound. Have you set the SDL-AUDIODRIVER environment variable to alsa

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but may I add that the world of raspberry pi seems to largely consist of unsubstantiated statements. Where are you getting this info? I see nothing about SDL and XFCE4 or PIXEL. SDL is certainly not a necessary component of audio on linux. That said, I tried setting SDL_AUDIODRIVER (note underscore), and it had no effect. `pimixer` was already showing "bcm2835 ALSA (Alsa mixer) (Default)" in the Sound Card drop-down.

Comment: Are you saying that when you right click on the sound icon (top right of the desktop), you can't choose the default device ?

Comment: I got that from debugging a port of a graphic app for the PI for the last two weeks. Asking if you tried something is not the same as stating a fact.

Comment: @Matt I only see HDMI and analog (the two broadcom / built-in options) when I right-click. USB audio only shows up via alsa command line. I've also verified that pulse audio is not running by default.

Answer (score 1):

**What is controlling the audio?**

According to [spl23 on the raspi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1075871#p1075871), the program that's controlling audio settings is volumealsa.

**What if I want audio right now?**

I have verified that Ubuntu MATE works fine with the USB DAC I have (Onyx Blackjack) with Firefox and other GUI tools.

Strangely, streaming audio pages seem not to work still (Amazon Music, SoundCloud), but YouTube does.

Comment: Also - as of most recent updates, Raspbian is allowing the GUI to access my USB audio device!