# What modifies my .asoundrc file every boot?

Tags: alsa

My .asoundrc file gets modified every boot. If I delete it, a new appears at reboot:

```
pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

If I make changes that differ from these, eg set `type plug`, then the above entry is appended to the file, effectively removing my changes. What is going on?!

Edit: If I wait 5 seconds after launching PIXEL at boot, then overwrite .asoundrc with this:

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave {
            pcm "hw:0,0"
        }
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

Then it works like I want. Is something in PIXEL smoking my file? How can I disable that?

Comment: Duplicate of [my asoundrc is modified every reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/54199), which does not have a correct answer.

Comment: Yep, it has an accepted answer but it isn't right.

Comment: I would recommend checking the boot logs. Unfortunately, I don't know how to tell you to do that. You also may need to increase the verbose level of the boot logs. Hopefully someone else can provide instructions to do this.

Comment: You can also look at the time stamp of the file to see when in the boot process the file is modified.

Comment: Have you tried making the file read only?

Comment: I noticed that in my case on raspbian stretch the file is rewritten every time my bluetooth speaker connects, maybe this is the case for you too?

Answer (score 0):

The *thing* that over write your user ALSA config is most likely the *lxpanel*. Within the *lxpanel* there are several applets (the clickable icons). The **lxplug-volume** applet has proven to be one of the culprits as can be seen in the code of [volumealsabt.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/lxplug-volume/blob/master/plugins/volumealsabt/volumealsabt.c).

Remove the Volume Applet by left clicking on the panel and selecting it, and then *delete*.

Check for updates to `lxpanel`, by running the following:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
apt list --upgradable

# Then check if the list contain any of these:
lxpanel
lxinput        
lxpanel-data    
lxplug-bluetooth
lxplug-ejecter  
lxplug-network  
lxplug-ptbatt   
lxplug-volume 


# If yes, then use sudo apt-get install <name>
```

If this doesn't resolve it, please see my other [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54199/my-asoundrc-is-modified-every-reboot).

Comment: You're recommending users not do a `sudo apt full-upgrade`? Why? Much easier than having us manually upgrade only certain packages.

Comment: @Botspot Because you will lose all your custom sound settings, and since QA is not done by RP org, people are left to do all the debugging of these kind of issues. So if you want to update and then post 10 other questions here for subsequent issues, please go ahead.