# .asoundrc file is rewritten on each boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, audio, alsa

i read all of the posts here and commentated on one of them but comment was deleted as it was a question i guess, so i mage my own now, sorry for that...

Ok the problem:

USB sound card mic is not working, but when i edit the ~/.asoundrc to:

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}
```

The mic and speakers start working, everything is great again!

and then i reboot and everything is back to:

```
pcm.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}
```

and after that nothing works again (whell sound works but mic does not)

i have disabled BCM driver load in boot.conf and aplay -l and arecord -l returns only USB sound card.

so the big question of the century is how can i force the config file to stay the same as i have written? read only doesnt work it just throws error and stops loading UI, config in /etc/ also does not work.
i have updated everything and upgraded also...

what now?

thanks!

Comment: which posts are "all of the posts here" - just for reference you understand

Comment: for example:https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54199/my-asoundrc-is-modified-every-reboot/88946#88946

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69821/what-modifies-my-asoundrc-file-every-boot

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58193/how-do-i-enable-usb-audio-for-gui-applications-on-raspbian-alsa-command-line-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

sorry don't have others saved if there are any, this is not the only place I've looked :D

Comment: All good, I just wanted to see what other answers were before duplicating an answer that doesn't work :p

Comment: Any ideas? It seems that the file is rewritten once the UI is loaded. bcs i added a script to crontab to execute after reboot and it does not work. also if i set .asoundrc to read only the UI wont load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it is weird but for now at least works...
i changed boot config file back to:

```
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
```

I had it turned off previously, and now it shows that it loaded bcm as a default device, but keeps the .asoundrc file alone and sends sound through the USB also the mic works...

Im confused, but yea...